# How should I create a project that acts as an engine for Android (ie will it need AndroidManifest etc...)

Tags: android

I intend to have a project that is simply an API that I will then use for other projects to build my applications on top of.

I find myself at the very beginning and already not knowing whic is the best practice for continuing (wish me luck on the rest of it).

My idea is a very common one I imagine. The idea of an engine built on top of the Android API which I can therefore reuse in my various upcoming projects.

So my Engine will require access to the Android API this is very clear, I will therefore need to have it somehow in the project but this is my question...

1. Do I make a new Android Project such that it will have its own AndroidManifest.xml etc? This seems like the incorrect way to do things as the Manifest will be of no use. The android projects that will be created for each individual android app will have their own manifests.
2. Or have a project with the Android API as a referenced library? Tgis seems like the propper way to do it but I cannot find any literature on the matter to confirm so.
3. Any other.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I make a new Android Project such that it will have its own AndroidManifest.xml etc?

You create [an Android library project](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html#LibraryProjects). It has a manifest.

> This seems like the incorrect way to do things as the Manifest will be of no use.

With recent additions to the tools, there are ways you can have items in the library's manifest be automatically added to host projects. That is optional, of course, particularly if there is nothing in the library that would need to be added to host projects.

> The android projects that will be created for each individual android app will have their own manifests.

Correct.

> Or have a project with the Android API as a referenced library?

An Android library project will automatically compile against your chosen build target.

Comment: Thanks, I know it was a total beginner question but I wanted to make sure I was doing things correctly before I moved very far along with it. There is actually quite a lot of litterature on this matter once you know what to look for. Thanks again.